# Hiding of menu items in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, user-interface, hide

I am developing one app.In that app I had created one main screen.On that main screen i had added one button field .When i clicked on that button field to open my popup screen it will open my popup screen but it also show menu items whatever i added for my main screen in front of screen.However i don't want to show those menu items but only want to open my popup screen on click of that button.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html#CONSUME_CLICK) style on your [ButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html#ButtonField%28java.lang.String,%20long%29), like below.

```java
ButtonField btn = new ButtonField("My Button", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
```